# How to change dictionary from one format into another?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm pretty sure this is a n00b question, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help appreciated.

I've got an application that generates a series of files and within each file is a dictionary formatted as:

`{date1:{key1:result1, key2:result2},date2:{key2:result3}}`

I want to figure out the daily average for each value. So I'd like to create one dictionary per unique key that aggregates results from across all the files:

`unique_key_dict = {date1:[file1_result, file2_result],date2:[file1_result, file2_result]}`

I won't know in advance the names of the keys or how many unique keys there will be, although it wont' be more than 25 unique keys across my entire dataset, and for speed reasons, I only want to open each file once.

How do I write the following in Python?

```
for date in file_dict:
    for key in file_dict[date]:
        # if key_dict does not exist from a previous file or date, create it
        # once the dictionary exists, append this value to the list tied to the date key.
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to dynamically create a dictionary using the name of the key. If I were dynamically printing their names I'd do `"dict_for_%s" % key` but I'm not trying to print, I'm trying to create dictionaries.

Also, I could just create a single massive dict... which is faster? A single massive dict or 15-25 separate dictionaries?

Comment: How are you storing the dicts in the files?

Comment: It's just JSON. Here's a sample: 
`{"2013-05-07T07:00:00+0000": {"recommended_pages": 1}, "2013-04-19T07:00:00+0000": {"page_profile": 1}, "2013-01-07T08:00:00+0000": {"mobile": 2, "page_profile": 1}}`

Comment: Are you trying to create a dictionary whose name is something like `dict_for_whatever`, i.e. dynamically create an object of a specific name?  If so, that's not a great idea, and you should do what @forefinger recommended and wrap it up in a dict.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to create. @DSM Why is it a bad idea? I've searched, but nothing even remotely related comes up for me in either Google or SO for "why is it a bad idea to dynamically create an object in python"

Comment: It's not a bad idea to dynamically create an object.  It's a bad idea to dynamically create *names*.  See [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.ca/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html), and links therein.  How do you plan on referring to these objects after you've made them?  Either you hardcode every name and have a lot of duplication, or you're going to have to store them in some structure to loop over like a list or dict.  But in either case, creating names dynamically isn't going to help.  What do you think that doing this will get you over using a dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does part of it:

```
unique_key_dict = {}
for date in file_dict:
  for key in file_dict[date]:
    if date not in unique_key_dict: unique_key_dict[date] = []
    unique_key_dict[date].append(file_dict[date][key])
```

Or perhaps you want

```
unique_key_dict = {}
for date in file_dict:
  for key in file_dict[date]:
    if key not in unique_key_dict: unique_key_dict[key] = {}
    if date not in unique_key_dict[key]: unique_key_dict[key][date] = []
    unique_key_dict[key][date].append(file_dict[date][key])
```

Then you have a dict which maps each key to a dict, and these dicts map dates to arrays of values.

To get averages after that:

```
for key in unique_key_dict:
  for date in unique_key_dict[key]:
    avg = sum(float(x) for x in unique_key_dict[key][date]) / len(unique_key_dict[key][date])
    print key, date, avg
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I generate the unique_key_dict part to test against?

Comment: First, I really appreciate the help! 

However, this only creates a single unique_key_dict, when I want to create separate dicts for each unique key... almost like `"dict_for_%s" % key` but I'm not printing, I'm trying to generate dictionaries.

Comment: That's not what you wrote above. Why do you want so many dicts?

Comment: Eh, I specifically wrote: _I want to figure out the daily average for each value. So I'd like to create one dictionary per unique key that aggregates results from across all the files_. I could create one massive dict, but I was curious how to do it this way instead. I don't know if one massive dict would be more memory efficient or not. The total number of unique keys should be no more than 25

Comment: If you want to do a single pass over the files, you would be holding all 25 dicts in memory at once anyway, so the memory usage should be the same.